# How to improve performance for get in Linked list?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I tried to implement a Linked list by myself and faced the question: "How I can get Node for **O(1) complexity**?"

Are there opportunities (or good practices) to improve "get" method? Do I need to add another data structure into Linked List? I read in some articles about using Hash Table into Linked List. Is it normal?

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  // O(1)
  addToTail(value) {
    let newNode = new Node(value);

    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
  }

  // O(n)
  get(value) {
    let cur = this.head;
    while (cur && cur.value !== value) {
      cur = cur.next;
    }

    return cur;
  }

  // O(n)
  remove(value) {
    let cur = this.head;
    let prev = null;
    while (cur && cur.value !== value) {
      prev = cur;
      cur = cur.next;
    }

    if (cur) {
      // First Node
      if (this.head === cur) {
        this.head = cur.next;
        if (this.head === null) {
          this.tail = null;
        }
      } else {
        // Not first Node
        prev.next = cur.next;

        if (cur.next === null) {
          this.tail = prev;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  print() {
    let cur = this.head;
    while (cur !== null) {
      console.log(cur.value);
      cur = cur.next;
    }
  }
}

const cars = ['Audio', 'BMW', 'Mazda', 'Toyota'];
const list = new LinkedList();
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  list.addToTail(cars[i])
}

list.remove('Audio')
list.addToTail('Kia')
list.addToTail('Lexus')
console.log(list.get('Mazda'));
```

Comment: *O(n)* performance for getting an element of a linked list is expected.

Comment: Vanilla linked list is O(n) for getting an element. Check it out-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718116/complexity-of-different-operations-on-different-data-structures-according-to-the/40718359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and faced the question: "How I can get Node for O(1) complexity?"

You can't. A linked list always requires *some* level of scanning. A pure singly-linked list is O(n), IIRC.

> I read in some articles about using Hash Table into Linked List. Is it normal?

It's not uncommon to have a map structure that does a hash of the key to find the right "bucket," where a "bucket" is a linked list or similar linearly-searched container for all of the entries whose keys hash the same. Basically, get is then:

- Do the hash for the key
- Look up the bucket by hash
- Search in the bucket for the key

At that point, though, the overall thing isn't a linked list anymore, it's more of a map. Even a map backed by hash tables isn't O(1), though it'll be better than O(n).

(I realize you're doing this for learning purposes, but I have to point to JavaScript's native `Map`, which does use hashing or (quoting the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-objects)) *"...other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection."*)